# How to save eclipse workspace from commandline when it hangs?

Tags: eclipse

Eclipse hangs for various reasons. The problem because of that the workspace goes back in time and loose many things like errors, included files etc. I am using eclipse CDT. Is there anyway I could save the workspace from commandline before I do `kill -9 $(pgrep eclipse)`?

Edit:
Is there a way to save eclipse when it functions normal? I know restarting eclipse will save but is there a better way?

Comment: I figure when it hangs, it won't respond to saves either?

Comment: Have you tried waiting for Eclipse? It can be very slow on some operations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't appear to be possible to save the workspace when Eclipse hangs.

Saving the workspace when Eclipse is still responding (According to [eclipse: explicitly saving project / workspace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2388902/eclipse-explicitly-saving-project-workspace)) is easiest accomplished by switching workspaces (To empty workspace an back, for example. File/Switch Workspace). In the same thread the plugin "saveui" is also referenced which can be configured to save the workspace often.